# How to enable the Direct Ship Flag for the product in catalog in Business Manager in Salseforce Commerce Cloud?

Tags: commerce-cloud

In product catalog, the Direct Ship Flag has the value "no data available". How to enable it?

Answer (score 1):

You should first "lock" the product for editing. Then you should be able to set the value you'd like for that attribute. (Be sure to click the "apply" button at the top or bottom of the page before moving on.)